# ListViewItem change text color using index

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to create a playlist.

But I have a problem to highlight the selected item indicated by the user and change the background color or the color of the text item that is played now.

Properties i want to show - what is play now (`int IndexToPlay`) what user selects (`SelectedIndex`)

The user should select only one item

I use WPF, MVVM, and I read a lot of posts, but unfortunately I have not found a solution.

```
<ListView Name="List"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="11" Margin="7,0,7,0.4" Grid.Row="9" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding MusicList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}"
    >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have IsSelected and IsPlaying properties in your ViewModel class:

```
public class MusicItem
{
    private bool _isPlaying;
    public bool IsPlaying
    {
        get
        {
            return _isPlaying;
        }
        set
        {
            _isPlaying = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
           _isSelected = value;
           OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

You can set the ItemContainerStyle to bind the IsSelected property and then you can use a style on the ItemTemplate with a DataTrigger to change the appearance of the ItemTemplate:

```
<ListView Name="List"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MusicList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                       <Style.Triggers>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPlaying}" Value="True">
                               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                           </DataTrigger>
                           <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                           </DataTrigger>
                       </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```